# Functions that simply call another function, bad design choice?

Tags: design, coding-style, code-quality, clean-code

I have a setup of a class that represents a building. This building has a floor plan, which has bounds.

The way I have it setup is like this:

```java
public struct Bounds {} // AABB bounding box stuff

//Floor contains bounds and mesh data to update textures etc
//internal since only building should have direct access to it no one else
internal class Floor {  
    private Bounds bounds; // private only floor has access to
}

//a building that has a floor (among other stats)
public class Building{ // the object that has a floor
    Floor floor;
}
```

These objects have their own unique reasons to exist as they do different things. However there is one situation, where I want to get a point locally to the building.

In this situation I am essentially doing:

```java
Building.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
```

This then has:

```java
public Vector3 GetLocalPoint(Vector3 worldPoint){    
    return floor.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
}
```

Which leads to this function in my `Floor` object:

```java
internal Vector3 GetLocalPoint(Vector3 worldPoint){
    return bounds.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
}
```

And then of course the bounds object actually does the math required.

As you can see these functions are pretty redundant as they just pass on to another function lower down. This doesn't feel smart to me - it smells like bad code thats going to bite me in butt some where down the line with code mess.

Alternatively I write my code like below but I have to expose more to public which I kinda don't want to do:

```java
building.floor.bounds.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
```

This also starts to get a bit silly when you go to many nested objects and leads to large rabbit holes to get your given function and you may end up forgetting where it is - which also smells like bad code design.

What is the correct way to design all this?

Comment: Your first approach sets interface boundaries and doesn't violate the Law of Demeter.

Comment: Consider using an [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). It reduces the indirections and also simplifies batch operations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so those redundant functions are pretty common ?

Comment: `"Functions that simply call another function"` That's a wrapper function, e.g., see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function And they can be very sensibly used, so not necessarily a `"bad design choice"` at all.

Comment: @WDUK: yes, they are pretty common in practice. That doesn't necessarily imply they're always the right thing to do, but often they are. As a rule of thumb, if I'm a user of Building and I just want a point localised to the frame of reference of the building, then I don't care about Floors or Bounds, so I want there to be a method Building.GetLocalPoint. Now, if that local point then has x and y co-ordinates that I also care about, but I already understand that points have co-ordinates, then I probably *don't* want separate Building.GetLocalX() and Y(), so the wrapping might well stop there.

Comment: It's less common with inheritance: If you think a building *is-a* floor (one with a roof on top) there is no need to override the floor's GetLocalPoint() method in the building. But inheritance has fallen somewhat out of favor -- because the coupling is looser and testability is better, people prefer composition (a building *has-a* floor; this is what you are using). With composition these pass-on calls are unavoidable.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica am i not already doing it compositely here ?

Comment: This is also common with the use of the [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), where one new service interacts with many. The only difference here is that your service wraps a single service (as shown), not multiple.

Comment: Delegation to a member is fine, but I'm curious why a Building has-a Floor instead of a sequence of Floors? If a building contained a list of floors, maybe the connection would be a little more indirect?

Comment: @WDUK Yes, you are using composition.

Comment: @DavidConrad there will be multiple floors but i wanted to simplify the concerns i had about my setup as i didn't want to be far into development then realise i  was in code hell lol

Comment: I love functions that do nothing but call another function. They are the easiest functions to code review, and they almost always do exactly what they say on the label.

Comment: Why did 2 people vote to close this question ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Never forget the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or **principle of least knowledge** is a design guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose coupling. The guideline was proposed by Ian Holland at Northeastern University towards the end of 1987, and can be succinctly summarized in each of the following ways:[1]
>
> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - **Only talk to your immediate friends**.
>
> The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little as possible about the structure or properties of anything else (**including its subcomponents)**, in accordance with the principle of "information hiding".
>   It may be viewed as a corollary to the principle of least privilege, which dictates that a module possess only the information and resources necessary for its legitimate purpose.

---

```java
building.floor.bounds.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
```

This code violates the LOD. Your current consumer somehow is required to know:

- That the building has a `floor`
- That the floor has `bounds`
- That the bounds have a `GetLocalPoint` method

But in reality, your consumer should only be handling the `building`, not anything inside of the building (it shouldn't be handling the subcomponents directly).

If **any** of these underlying classes change structurally, you're suddenly also required to change this consumer, even though he may be several levels up from the class you actually changed.
This starts infringing on the separation of layers you have, as a change affects multiple layers (more than just its direct neighbors).

```java
public Vector3 GetLocalPoint(Vector3 worldPoint){    
    return floor.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);
}
```

Suppose you introduce a second type of building, one without a floor. I can't think of an real-world example, but I'm trying to show a generalized use case, so let's assume that `EtherealBuilding` is such a case.

Because you have the `building.GetLocalPoint` method, you are able to change its workings without the consumer of your building being aware of it, e.g.:

```java
public class EtherealBuilding : Building {
    public Vector3 GetLocalPoint(Vector3 worldPoint){    
        return universe.CenterPoint; // Just a random example
    }
}
```

What's making this harder to understand is that there is no clear use case for a building without a floor. I don't know your domain and I can't make a judgment call on if/how that would occur.

But development guidelines are generalized approaches that forgo specific contextual applications. If we change the context, the example becomes clearer:

```java
// Violating LOD

bool isAlive = player.heart.IsBeating();

// But what if the player is a robot?

public class HumanPlayer : Player {
    public bool IsAlive() {
        return this.heart.IsBeating();
    }
}

public class RobotPlayer : Player {
    public bool IsAlive() {
        return this.IsSwitchedOn();
    }
}

// This code works for both human and robot players, and thus wouldn't need to be changed when new (sub)types of players are developed.

bool isAlive = player.IsAlive();
```

Which proves the point why the method on the `Player` class (or any of its derived classes) **has a purpose, even if its current implementation is trivial**.

---

> ***Sidenote***
>   *For the sake of example, I've skirted a few tangential discussions, such as how to approach inheritance. These are not the focus of the answer.*

Comment: One of the purposes is that it adds meaning. Point inside a building vs point inside a floor is different semantics even if the outcome is the same and the implementation trivial (but the use does not know that)

Comment: You could have important points which are in-between floors, e.g. the midpoint of a stairwell (which commonly have things like fire extinguishers or cable boxes that you might want to track).

Comment: Rather than trying to think of use-case for a building without a floor, you could just use a building with 2 floors or a hundred floors (so building.floor would have aetherial meaning - is it the first one, is it some abstraction of all of them, is it the middle one)

Comment: @Delioth: It works as a more realistic scenario, but it requires to change the general "building" contract to have multiple floors (or require a level parameter) - I was trying to stick to the contract as designed to lower confusion. Problems like these are quite susceptible to "yes but you could also do [...]" answers which shift the bad practice around but don't remove it.

Comment: @Flater Ah, of course. I made assumptions that weren't actually in the OP example code (notably, I had misread and assumed there was a Building-ish interface that had the `GetLocalPoint` method and didn't require implementers to have a `floor`, which would make `Building` and `NStoryBuilding` valid implementations of the interface)

Comment: A constant-flush outhouse or privy might not have a floor - just a seat suspended over a stream or river...

Answer (score 22):

If you have such methods occasionally here and there, it may just be a side effect (or price to pay, if you will) of a consistent design.

If you have *a lot* of them then I would consider it a sign that this design is itself problematic.

In your example, *maybe there shouldn't be* a way to "get a point locally to the building" from outside the building and instead the building's methods should be at a higher level of abstraction and work with such points only internally.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that you know the implementation of Building for a moment. Someone else has written it. Maybe a supplier who only gives you compiled code. Or some contractor who actually starts writing it next week.

All you know is the interface for Building and the calls you make to that interface. They all look quite reasonable, so you are fine.

Now you put on a different coat and suddenly you are the implementor of Building. You don't know the implementation of Floor, you just know the interface. You use the Floor interface to implement your Building class. You know the interface for Floor and the calls you make to that interface to implement your Building class, and they all look quite reasonable, so you are fine again.

All in all, no problem. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The famous "Law of Demeter" is a law that dictates what kind of code to write, but it does not explain anything useful. Flater's answer is fine because it gives examples, but I would not call these "violation of/compliance with the law of Demeter". If the "Law of Demeter" is enforced where you are, please get in touch with your local Demeter Police Station, they will be happy to sort out the issues with you.

Remember that you are always master of the code you write, and therefore, between creating "delegating functions" and not writing them, it is a matter of your own judgement. There is no crisp line, so no one sharp rule can be defined. On the contrary, we can find cases, like Flater did, where creating such functions are plain useless, and where creating such functions are useful. (**Spoiler:** In the former case, the fix is to inline the function. In the latter, the fix is to create the function)

Examples where it is useless to define a delegating function include when the sole reason would be:

- To access a member of an object returned by a member, when the member is not an implementation detail that should be encapsulated.
- Your interface member is correctly implemented by .NET's [quasi-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942772/why-is-a-base-class-in-c-sharp-allowed-to-implement-an-interface-contract-withou)
- To be Demeter-compliant

Examples where it is useful to create a delegating function include:

- Factoring out a call chain that is repeated over and over
- When the language forces you to, e.g. implement an interface member by delegating to another member or simply calling another function
- When the function you call is not at the same conceptual level as the other calls at the same level (e.g. a `LoadAssembly` call at the same level than plugin introspection)

Answer (score 0):

building.floor.bounds.GetLocalPoint(worldPoint);

is BAD.

Objects should only deal with their immediate neighbors
because your system will be VERY hard to change otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to just call functions. There are event many design patterns which are using that technique, for example adapter and facade but also to some extend patterns like decorator, proxy and many more.

It's all about levels of abstractions. You should not mix concepts from different levels of abstractions. To do so you need sometimes to make call to inner objects so that your client will not be forced to do it himself.

For example (Car example will be simpler):

You have Driver, Car and Wheel objects. In real world, in order to drive a car, do you have driver doing something directly with wheels or does he only interact with car as a whole?

How to know that something is NOT ok:

- Encapsulation is broken, inner objects are available in public API. (e.g. code like car.Wheel.Move()).
- SRP principle is broken, objects are doing many different things (e.g. preparing e-mail message text and actually sending it in same object).
- It is difficult to unit test particular class (e.g. there are many dependencies).
- There are different domain experts (or company departments) handling things which you handle in same class (e.g. sales and package delivery).

Potential problems when breaking Law of Demeter:

- Hard unit testing.
- Dependency on the internal structure of other objects.
- High coupling between objects.
- Exposing internal data.